# SQL join table with 12 column composite PK with itself painlessly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a composite natural primary key that involves 12 columns (c1, c2, ..., c12).

I want to write a self join query:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1 AS a
JOIN T1 AS b ON a.c1 = b.c1 AND a.c2 = b.c2 AND ... AND a.c12 = b.c12;
```

This join is a pain to write. Is there a better way?

Comment: A 12 column primary key? I think the best solution would be to introduce an auto increment ID column as primary key. You can still have a unique key on those 12 columns.

Comment: *"This join is a pain to write"* because you have a 12 column key. Keys, normally are just a single column or at most 2 (in a composite key table). They certainly aren't 12 columns wide. This smells like a big design flaw.

Comment: `NATURAL JOIN` isn't a valid `JOIN` operation in T-SQL, @RaduGheorghiu . SQL Server only has `INNER`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `FULL` ([Join Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#join-type)). The latter 3 all being a form of `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Just a note, `natural join` is a pain... and should not be encouraged.

Comment: @Larnu, whether or not it smells like a big design flaw, I am not sure. It is an analytical table not a transactional one.

Comment: That code also implies a join to the same table; I assume that isn't actually what you're doing.

Comment: Even analytical tables don't have 12 column keys, @LudovicAubert .

Comment: @Larnu: it is actually a join between two snapshots of the same table. Same structure but different data.

Comment: How about a computed column ?

Comment: Someone suggested using a JOIN USING syntax instead of JOIN ON. I though it was brilliant. But he later removed it... Unfortunately, it is not supported by SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, if you must have a 12 column "key", I would `DROP` that key, and create a computed column that concatenates all the values, and then create the key on that. This is overly simplified, but this should give you the gist:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (C1 int NOT NULL,
                            C2 int NOT NULL,
                            C3 int NOT NULL,
                            C4 int NOT NULL,
                            C5 int NOT NULL,
                            C6 int NOT NULL,
                            C7 int NOT NULL,
                            C8 int NOT NULL,
                            C9 int NOT NULL,
                            C10 int NOT NULL,
                            C11 int NOT NULL,
                            C12 int NOT NULL);
GO
--Create a unique index, instead of a PK
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_YourTable ON dbo.YourTable (C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9,C10,C11,C12);
GO
--Add the new column
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD K AS CONCAT(C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9,C10,C11,C12);
--Set it as the PK 
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY (K);
```

Then your `JOIN` becomes as simple as:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable YT1
     JOIN dbo.YourTable YT2 ON YT1.K = YT2.K;
```

*Note: this **assumes** all your columns are `NOT NULL`. This will likely not work correctly if they* can *have `NULL` values.*

Comment: There is a lot of SQL code that manipulates this table. Don't want to change it. Could K be a computed column ?

Comment: `K` **is** a computed column in  that example, @LudovicAubert ...

Comment: If there is an insert into all columns with an implicit column list, will that code be broken ? That is my concern because there is potentially a lot of impacted legacy code.

Comment: @Larnu . . . The columns are `NOT NULL` if they are components of a primary key.

Comment: Yes, @GordonLinoff, but as I'm removing the PK, and creating a `UNIQUE INDEX`, I wanted to add that caveat; as a `UNIQUE INDEX`, *does* allow `NULL` values.

Comment: It *shouldn't* have any impact, @LudovicAubert .

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make sense.  Why would you use a self join on a primary key?  Your code is equivalent to:

```
select t.*, t.*
from t1 t;
```

That is, the row match is 1-1.  The `join` is superfluous because it matches exactly one row, the referencing row (that is how primary keys work).

To me, a "natural" key with 12 columns doesn't seem so natural to me.  I would suggest using a synthetic key using an identity column:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    t1_id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    c1 ? NOT NULL,
    -- rest of columns here
    UNIQUE (c1, c2, c3, . . . )
);
```

For foreign key references, use the identity.  Don't repeat the columns!

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (
    t2_id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    t2_id INT REFERENCES t1(t1_id),
    -- columns specific to this table
);
```

If you want the values of `c1` and so on, use `JOIN` to get them.

Comment: Table is an output analytical table and there are no foreign key references.

Comment: "self join on a primary key" was here to cut a long story short. In reality, I fill up the table, keep a copy, empty it, fill it up again and keep a second copy. In the end I want to compare both copies.

Comment: @LudovicAubert . . . Perhaps if you asked a question related to your actual problem, you would get more useful answers.  The example that starts your question is not useful.

Comment: Your answer is still relevant to me. using JOIN USING (c1, c2, c3, ...)  instead of JOIN ON a.c1=b.c1 AND a.c2=b.c2 AND a.c3=b.c3 ... complements it well. In this particular case, the sole purpose of this composite pk is to have a unique constraint.

Comment: Oups, just realized JOIN USING is not supported by SQL Server

Comment: @LudovicAubert . . . Unfortunately not.  You need to list the keys.  Another option is to concatenate the values together as a computed column.  Then you can just `join` using a single column.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to write your joins without changing the underlying table structures, you can query PK's columns and build your SQL as a result of a `SELECT`. Something like the following:

Setup example:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
    C1 INT,
    C2 INT,
    C3 INT,
    C4 INT,
    C5 INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5))
```

Query:

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(100) = 'T1'
DECLARE @SQLTableAlias_1 VARCHAR(5) = 'a'
DECLARE @SQLTableAlias_2 VARCHAR(5) = 'b'

SELECT 
    TableName = KU.TABLE_NAME,
    PrimaryKeyColumn = KU.COLUMN_NAME,
    SQL = 
        @SQLTableAlias_1 + '.' + QUOTENAME(KU.COLUMN_NAME) + 
        ' = ' + 
        @SQLTableAlias_2 + '.' + QUOTENAME(KU.COLUMN_NAME) +
        CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(*) OVER () = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY KU.ORDINAL_POSITION) 
            THEN '' 
            ELSE ' AND ' 
        END
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KU ON 
        TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND
        TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE
    KU.table_name = @tableName
ORDER BY 
    KU.TABLE_NAME, 
    KU.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Result:

```
TableName   PrimaryKeyColumn    SQL
T1          C1                  a.[C1] = b.[C1] AND 
T1          C2                  a.[C2] = b.[C2] AND 
T1          C3                  a.[C3] = b.[C3] AND 
T1          C4                  a.[C4] = b.[C4] AND 
T1          C5                  a.[C5] = b.[C5]
```

Then just copy/paste the SQL column.